# How to define agent / node in Jenkins Post block

Tags: jenkins-groovy

My post block is under main pipeline (not under any stage). In that post block, I want to use agent / node. I tried with multiple syntax but always getting error.

```
    post{ 
          success {
            agent {
                label{
                    label "${env.BUILD_SERVER}"
                    customWorkspace "${env.WRKSPACE}"
                } 
                steps{
                    email_report("SUCCESS")
                    }
            }
            }
}
```

What will be correct syntax ?

Answer (score 3):

If you don't specify an agent the post section will be executed on the agent defined for the main pipeline - which is usually the common case.

However if you want to change the post execution agent for specific steps you can use the `node` keyword from the scripted pipeline syntax within a script block:

```
post{
    success{
        script {
           // Use 'node' keyword with the relevant label
           node(env.BUILD_SERVER) { 
               // your agent specific code
           }
        }
        ...
    }
}
```